# Блокировка горутин (не deadlock)

Tags: golang

Как заблокировать множество горутин, кроме одной? А затем быстро разблокировать их?

Суть задачи в том, что некоторое множество горутин могут одномоментно получить от API некоего сервиса одну и ту же ошибку.

И эту ошибку должна разрулить одна единственная горутина (взять из deque новый ключ и затем сделать запрос API, чтобы проверить его.
Если ключ рабочий - разблокировать прочие горутины. Если нет - взять еще один ключ, или передать такую возможность другой горутине, а самой заблокироваться в ожидании). И так до получения от API кода 200.

Не получается придумать правильный алгоритм (подход) для такой логики, чтобы только одна горутина могла бы обращаться к очереди с ключами до тех пор, пока там вообще что-то есть или пока не найден рабочий ключ.

На текущий момент горутины после ошибки просто блокируются через sleep c последовательным увеличением  (инкремент залочен мьютексом) переменной шага таймаута.
Таким образом шанс разрулить получает та горутина, чей таймаут ожидания меньше прочих. Это работает (не очень хорошо, там еще приходится использовать цикл с условной переменной,

```
for trs.Suspended {
    log.Debug("Suspended")
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
}
```

пока она true - горутина лочится в нем). Но такой подход мне совсем не нравится.

Comment: используйте каналы для синхронизации между горутинами (для этого их и создавали) первая  получившая ошибку горутина сообщает в канал остальным

Comment: Я думал о таком механизме. Но если бы это было так просто - я бы так и сделал. Покажите пример реализации, если несложно.

Answer (score 1):

1. Вам в таком случае не нужны горутины (если всегда работает ТОЛЬКО ОДИН обработчик). Достаточно создать словарь вызовов соответствующего обработчика в однотипным объектах (лучше чтобы элементы словаря были интерфейсами -- можно отдать ссылки на любой тип, который удовлетворяет этому интерфейсу). Также замечу, что когда ОЧЕНЬ МНОГО горутин -- рантайм тратит существенное время на обработку состояния каналов (на моём рабочем ноуте 1200 каналов требует 5% процессорного времени на ровном месте -- пришлось сокращать эту басню).

```go
mapRunner:=make(map[name]*IRunner, n)
sigName:=<-chanSig
mapRanner[sigName].Run()
```

Эта схема работы называется "селектор".
2) Если всё же вам РЕАЛЬНО НУЖНА АСИНХРОННОСТЬ -- сделайте словарь каналов с выходом в каждой горутине. Словарём каналов должна владеть управляющая горутина. Как только приходит сигнал с нужным параметром -- управляющая горутина засылает в соответствующий канал сигнал. В качестве словаря также можно использовать интерфейсы, но тогда указанные интерфейсы должны иметь методы для запихивания сигналов в свои каналы и вызовы закрытия этих каналов для прерывания работы горутин (это более универсально, но требует больше работы).

```go
const(
   SIG = 0
)
mapRunner:=make(map[name]*TRunner, n)
sigName:=<-chanSig
mapRunner[sigName]<-SIG
```

Эта схема работы называется "демультиплексор".

Comment: "если всегда работает ТОЛЬКО ОДИН обработчик".  Горутин - много, а отдельного обработчика ошибок для сабжа у меня и вовсе нет. По сути обработчиком является каждая горутина сама по себе - у меня там длинный switch по номерам ошибок и на каждый сase своя логика.  И для большинства ошибок этого хватает. Но когда нужно резко сменить ключ API (достав его из очереди), мешает конкурентность (мьютексы  и sync.Once тут никак не помогают).

Comment: Речь про то, что обработчики остаются обработчиками. Но к ним нужна управляющая горутина. Если нужно сменить ключ API  -- нужна другая группа обработчиков ровно с такой же управляющей горутиной.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге решение получилось такое.
В main функции заранее создается канал на один тикет.

```
trs.Ticket = make(chan bool,1)
trs.TicketDelay = time.Duration(5000) 
trs.TimeBlocking = time.Duration(1000) 
trs.Ticket <- true
```

В который сразу пишется одно значение - *билет-проходка*.
В горутинах, которые что-то запрашивают и могут получить ошибки добавлен select для чтения из канал Ticket.

Логика такая: получили ошибку, идем в if, если ошибка подходит, идем в select, кто-то первый успевает прочитать (достать) ticket, выходит из select'а, идет в switch - решает (пытается решить) проблему.
Отдает тикет обратно, чтобы какая-нибудь другая горутина смогла им воспользоваться, если проблема не решилась (горутины опять получили ошибку).

Горутины, которым тикет не достался блокируются на канале-таймере (1 сек), затем возвращаются в цикл запросов и пробуют снова сделать запрос.
Если опять ошибка, опять кто-то берет тикет, кто-то ждет, ну и так до победного....

```
...
    defer done.Wg.Done()
    TASKLOOP:
        for {
    
            select {
    
            case <-trs.ctx.Done():
                YAPI = &YandexAPIError{500, "The task was canceled", trs.ctx.Err()}
                break TASKLOOP
            default:
                resp, err := trs.API.Translate(task.Lang, task.Text)
    
                ... какой-то код
                // смотрим что за ошибка, если из списка - пробуем решить
                if contains([]int{401, 402, 404, 405, 406},
                    resp.Code) {
                    
                    select {
                    // канал на один тикет - кто успел взять, тот и решает проблему
                    case  <-trs.Ticket:
                        break // выходим из select и идем в switch
                    // здесь блокируемся, если билетика нет, а потом идем делать новый запрос
                    case <-time.After(trs.TimeBlocking * time.Millisecond):
                        goto TASKLOOP
                    }
                }
                
                
                switch resp.Code {
                    
                    .... много других кейсов
                    
                    case 405, 406: // 'Session is invalid', 'Session has expired',
                    
                        trs.mutex.Lock()
                        log.Errorf("[SESSION][task:%d][code:%d] EXPIRED or INVALID %s",
                            task.Id, resp.Code, trs.API.Id)
                        change := trs.ChangeSession(resp) // меняем session id
                        trs.mutex.Unlock()
                        // если получилось взять из очереди новый ключ\session_id
                        if change {
                            log.Warnf("[CHANGE SESSION] %s", trs.API.Id)
                            // немножко тормозим отдачу билетика в канал
                            time.Sleep(trs.TicketDelay * time.Millisecond) 
                            trs.Ticket <- true  // возвращаем билетик обратно
                            goto TASKLOOP       // идем на новый виток запросов
                        } else {
                            // ну если ничего не вышло - в очереди больше нет ключей\session_id
                            YAPI = &YandexAPIError{resp.Code, resp.Message, err}
                            log.Errorf("[CHANGE SESSION] %s", NotFoundAPISessionID)
                            trs.ctx.Cancel() // отменяем все задания
                            break TASKLOOP // завершаем горутину
                        }
                
                }
                 
        } // конец цикла            
        
        if YAPI != nil {
            task.Err = YAPI
            done.TaskChan <- task
            log.Errorf("[TRANSLATE][%d] FAIL %#v", task.Id, YAPI)
        } else {
            log.Debugf("[TRANSLATE][%d] DONE!", task.Id)
        }
```

Не знаю, насколько это решение простое и гениальное, но я до него долго доходил :-)
Можно покритиковать. Всем спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Решение всегда хорошо. Но. Может сложиться ситуация, когда тикет гуляет по горутинам и ни одна из них не может его закрыть. Если в контексте нет дедлайна -- через некоторое время может оказаться, что все горутины забиты такими "гулящими" тикетами. Надо предусмотреть возможность принудительного закрытия такого тикета по какому-либо признаку.